# How to model meme man

Tags: modeling, sculpting, topology

im trying to make a model called Meme man for a game im making.  There is only one picture of this character on the internet and you will see if you look it up, he is the face from the stonks meme.  I am cluless on how to make him, do i just sculpt away until i get a similar model or is there a more intelligent and less laborious approach? Thanks.[image]

Comment: I think starting from a sphere and sculpting from there would be a good start. Use a dragging brush to make the neck, flatten the face, although I don't have much sculpt experience. "Meme man" has a humanish head so I would recommend you search for beginner guides on sculpting humans.

Comment: please show some pictures here so that we don't have to search and guess what you're talking about. Why don't you model it in a basic way, then maybe sculpt if you want to add details?

Comment: There are three downloadable versions on Sketchfab.